# Why can $\ln x$ be integrated over $[0,1]$, yet $\frac{1}{x}$ can't?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Why can $\ln x$ be integrated over $[0,1]$, yet $\frac{1}{x}$ can't?

Both have singularities at $0$, yet we can still integrate $\ln x$ in the specified domain. Why is this?

Comment: $\ln(x)$ is not defined on $[-1,0]$

Comment: Do you mean $(0,1]$?

Comment: Oops, I've fixed the domain. It should be $[0, 1]$.

Comment: The problem with $\frac{1}{x}$ is not that it is undefined at $x=0$. The problem is that if you integrate over $(\epsilon,1]$ then the limit as $\epsilon\to0$ is infinite. That is not true for $\ln x$.

Comment: Because $|\ln x|\ll\frac1x$ when $x\to0^+$. Well, not "because" of this comparison but this comparison helps to understand why.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you want to compute $$\int_0^1 \ln x d x.$$
This is an improper integral and you compute it (if it exists) as a limit

$$\int_0^1 \ln x d x = \lim_{a\rightarrow 0}\int_a^1 \ln x d x =
\lim_{a\rightarrow 0}[x \ln x - x]_a^1=
\lim_{a\rightarrow 0}(-1-a\ln a +a ) = -1$$
where I have used that $x \ln x - x$ is a antiderivative of $\ln x$ and the well-known limit $\lim_{a\rightarrow 0}(a\ln a) = 0.$ It you want to integrate $1/x$ the same procedure would lead to $\lim_{a\rightarrow 0}(\ln a),\;$ but this does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not a function with such a singularity can be integrated on an interval or not, is a consequence of how we define the so called *improper integral* on that interval. I suppose you know how improper integrals are defined, so perhaps you're looking for some intuition.

You can compare this with integrals on intervals stretching to infinity: the integral of $\tfrac{1}{x^2}$ is finite on $[1,+\infty)$ while the integral of $\tfrac{1}{x}$ on the same interval isn't. If you [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%7B1%2Fx,1%2Fx%5E2%7D%20on%20%5B1%2F2,10%5D) both functions, you can get an intuitive feeling for this: if you look at the (unbounded) region between the function's graph and the $x$-axis, from $x=1$ but stretching to infinity, it can be possible to associate a finite number with this region which can be interpreted as the area. For this area to remain finite, the function needs to decrease (drop to $0$) *"sufficiently fast"*. This is the case for $\tfrac{1}{x^2}$ but not for $\tfrac{1}{x}$.

Similarly, returning to your example, you can look at the [graphs](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%7B-ln(x),%201%2Fx%7D%20on%20%5B0,1%5D) of $\tfrac{1}{x}$ and $\ln x$ (or $-\ln x$ for an easier comparison in the first quadrant). On $(0,1]$, there is an unbounded region between the graph, the $x$-axis and the $y$-axis. It is clear from the graphs that the region corresponding to $-\ln x$ is *smaller* than the region corresponding to $\tfrac{1}{x}$. When it is possible to associate a finite area with such a region, the corresponding improper integral converges.

Although you cannot tell from looking at the graphs if the integrals will converge or not, it is clear that **if** only one converges, it'll be the one of the function $\ln x$ (or $-\ln x$ in the linked plot).

To check whether or not such an improper integral exists (i.e. *converges*), you use the definition and calculate the required limit:
$$\int_0^1 \ln x \,\mbox{d}x = \lim_{a \to 0^+} \int_a^1 \ln x \,\mbox{d}x = -1$$
while
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \,\mbox{d}x = \lim_{a \to 0^+} \int_a^1 \frac{1}{x} \,\mbox{d}x = +\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

It's not really that strange. The same behavior can be seen for the function $x\mapsto x^{-1/2}$, which is integrable over $(0,1]$, but its derivative isn't.

Whenever you have a continuous function $f$ on $[0,1]$ which is twice differentiable on $(0,1]$ and
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)=\pm\infty
$$
the same situation *can* appear: $f'(x)$ is certainly integrable over $(0,1]$, but $f''(x)$ may not be.

In the $\ln x$ case, the function $f$ is
$$
\begin{cases}
x(\ln x-1) & \text{if $0<x\le1$}\\[4px]
0 & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}
$$
The fact that $\ln x$ has an antiderivative that can be extended by continuity at $0$ implies that
$$
\int_0^1 \ln x\,dx
$$
converges; on the other hand,
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\,dx
$$
does not converge.

Similarly, for $x\mapsto x^{-1/2}$, the function $f$ is $f(x)=2\sqrt{x}$.

You may try your hand into finding a function $f$ satisfying the above requirements and such that both $f'$ and $f''$ are integrable over $(0,1]$.